# SSIS ORA-12638 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am using visual studio 2017 and I am trying to create a SSIS package that connects to oracle. I am getting the ORA-12638: Credential Retrieval Failed. The server connection and the username and password that I am using works. I can connect using the same information through a linked server in SQL Management Studio and SQL Oracle Developer. 
I have made the SQLNET.ora change to SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE). I have also ran the tnsping.exe for the server that I am connecting too and verified that I changed the correct file.

How can I make a oracle connection in SSIS to oracle?

Comment: Are you receiving this error when trying to create a Connection Manager in the SSIS project file using Visual Studio 2017?  If not, at what point is the error taking place?

Comment: yes i am receiving this error when creating the connection in the connection manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) bundle which includes "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio" from oracle.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/vs2012welcome-1835382.html